# How do I build a toolbar in my title bar?

Tags: cocoa

I have to implement a custom toolbar for my application, where a button will be placed on the side of exit, maximize and minimize buttons.

I tried to work with the toolbar element on XCode, but it always put elements below these buttons and not on the side.

App Store application implement this feature, like you can see in this image.

[image: AppStore-like toolbar]

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to start with this open source code (https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) to give you the correct title bar style, and then position buttons in the titlebar.